# Is it possible to join a table to itself

Tags: sql, join

I have a query that joins two tables together.   In table O I have an employee ID, which I join to the HR table to retrieve the employee name:

```
inner join hr AS hr on o.syscreator = hr.res_id
```

Also on the HR table is the employees manager, but the value is only the employee ID of the manager.  Therefore to retrieve the full name of the manager, would I need to use a self join?  I could only find examples of self join using the FROM table, in this case it's the join table.

```
select o.ordernr,
       o.refer,
       o.orddat,
       o.afldat,
       o.magcode,
       o.user_id,
       o.status, 
       o.represent_id,
       o.crdnr,
       o.ord_debtor_name,
       o.ord_AddressLine1,
       ord_PostCode,
       ord_City,
       ord_StateCode,
       o.ord_landcode,
       o.ord_Phone,
       o.ord_contactperson, 
       o.ord_contactemail,
       o.syscreated,
       h.fullname AS RepName,
       h.repto_id AS ManagerID
from order o
inner join humres AS hr on o.syscreator = hr.res_id
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes:  tname AS t1 join tname AS t2 on (condition).  A search should turn up examples.

Comment: You question should've been "Is it possible to join **with** the same table more than once"?  And the answer is "yes" providing you use different aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sure bring the same table twice - you just need to use a different alias.

I think that you want:

```
select 
    o.ordernr, 
    ..., 
    h.fullname AS RepName, 
    h.repto_id AS ManagerID,
    hr_mgr.fullname as MgrName
from order o 
inner join humres AS hr on o.syscreator = hr.res_id
inner join humres AS hr_mgr on hr_mgr.res_id = hr.repto_id
```